# Run Bash Script as Root

Tags: bash, password, sudo, root

Is there some way I can run a Bash script as root without being prompted for a password every time? I'm attempting to automate the process of starting my LAMPP install, which requires me running a couple of sudo commands to start and stop services. Optimally, I'd like to build this into an executable file, so all I'd have to do is click an icon. ;)

Obviously, I have the password, so that's not an issue. I just want to take my laziness one step farther and not have to enter it every time I start my localhost. After all, that's what programming is all about, right?

Comment: You can automate starting services such as LAMP on boot up; there should be no need to use a sudo-bash hack.

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't necessarily want my localhost running all the time. Just when I actually need it.

Answer (score 7):

You could add the script to your `sudoers` configuration file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then find the following:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

add after:

```
 your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

CTRL+X and confirm.

Comment: Okay, I did something wrong, but I don't know what it was. It's still prompting for a password on both of the commands. :S

The sudoers file edit:
`scotty ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/lampp/startup.sh`

The few lines of my executable script:
`#!/bin/bash

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startapache
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql`

Comment: Obviously the above scripts span multiple lines, but the comments here don't show it.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: @jasmines, I think you should at least give a warning for the process.

Comment: @jasmines Hey, sorry it took so long to get back to this. Been up to my ears in work lately. Anyway, yes, I did reboot, and the executable file is still asking for my password.

Comment: And [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/209677) is why using [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can open a terminal, then "sudo gnome-terminal", enter the password and just copy, paste the commands to install LAMPP. Or you can write a script, "run.sh" for example, and run "sudo sh run.sh". Hope that helps.

Comment: OP was asking for ways to run WITHOUT entering password. If you include modifying sudoers file to allow running just this script with NOPASSWORD, it can be an answer. In its present form, however, it is invalid.