# Can we install a package through a shell script?

Tags: scripts, sudo

I'm trying to write a shell script so that when I reinstall my Ubuntu again. I could just run script and retain all the packages. And I'm planning to pass password in form of argument.

My question here is how can i enter into `sudo` domain without manually entering password. As I'm also planning to design a UI where it can't access the terminal there.

**Ex:**

```
./recover.sh password
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Bash Script as Root](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153402/run-bash-script-as-root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use...

```
echo password | sudo -S recover.sh
```

Password being your sudo password.

From sudo manpage..

> -S, --stdin
>   Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just run the script as superuser?

```
sudo sh recover.sh
```

Comment: ya that works when you directly access from **terminal**. But in UI you can only give a command .. watever you do it shoud be in the command

Comment: Look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/496204/specify-password-for-sudo-in-script?rq=1

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that i want to pass **password** in form of `argument`. There is  no such thing there

Comment: That question is basically a duplicate of this and he explained why its a bad idea but he said "You can echo the password to sudo using the -s option."

Comment: No you have misunderstood my question. Here my logic is not only limited to recovery, but it is also covering `UI`. And consider you are creating a UI and if u link a button with your script. Then you can only pass a command like `./install.sh password` . But you cant expect the any output from terminal.

Comment: Consider if i take your advice there and link command `sudo ./install.sh` you just can't expect the system to pop out a terminal to ask password.

Comment: That' s why I'm `concatenating` the command with password and passing the command

Comment: I did misunderstand your question. Sorry if i'm being a noob but wouldn't running the program with gksudo also make whatever command run by that program to also be run by the superuser.